# How can I read siteminder headers in my ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, siteminder

I need to read the user name from the siteminder authentication happened in my ruby on rails application. How can i do that?

I tried reading from request.headers and request.env - they are returning null.
any pointers will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

It can be read using request in ruby.
request.headers["SM-USER"]